# PhpStorm и ошибка Invalid privatekey

Tags: phpstorm, ssh, ssh-key

Работаю на macOS Mojave

Сгенерировал ssh ключи с помощью команды `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

С помощью терминала командой `ssh root@ip` подключаюсь успешно!

Но PhpStorm отказывается принимать `~/.ssh/id_rsa` файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему

Сгенерировав **ssh ключи** этой командой `ssh-keygen -m PEM -C "email"`